# I miss the site stats from Beta

Tags: discussion

In beta the site had stats in the right sidebar....

(from another beta site)

[image]

I kind of miss those stats for GD.SE. I understand that the stats are imperative in beta and could possibly be, well, non-advantageous (is that a word?) when live.

Not a big deal, but thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 4):

I liked it too. You can still get the stats, but not as conveniently. Go [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) and just search for "Graphic Design" (no anchor to link directly to unfortunately).

[image: site stats page]

Comment: That's helpful. It was easier to just look to the right though :)

Comment: You can also see them on [the proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design).

Comment: Those are old stats @AbbyT.Miller and appear to have stopped being calculated once the site left beta.

Comment: Huh! I didn't realize Area 51 did that. Learn something new every day.

Comment: Ooh, we're #17 in visits per day! 17 out of, erm, lots

Comment: for anyone else too lazy to type `graphic d...`, typing **`c d`** into "find" takes you straight to our site

Comment: Deleted my comment, I forgot to switch to list view to see all the information.